# Static analysis of probable wrong responsibility

Tags: java, ant, build, static, checkstyle

I started seeing lot of smalll private methods that takes in some object and solely interact with it, These methods should actually being added in wrong place, Which in reality should atleast be a static method in that class.

I am actually looking for some static analysis tool which reports these kind of issues so that i can pull them out to the appropriate classes that it acts on. Is there a checkstyle rule or some other static analysis tool that would help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try findbugs http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: But i dont see how i could add a check like that with it. Is there a list of checks it performs somewhere?

Comment: The first thing I'd do is check the FindBugs plugins feature if you want to add new checks.  The list of bugs it already searches for is [here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html).